# How can I make `fill-paragraph` on selected text respect indentation in AUCTeX?

Tags: indentation, auctex, fill-paragraph, selection

Using `fill-paragraph` in AUCTeX normally respects the given indentation. However, if I use `fill-paragraph` on a selection, only the first line will be indented, the other lines won't. Is there a way to correct this?

---

*Example*. I have the following LaTeX code

```
\begin{proposition}
    For every right-angled triangle with side \(a,b\) and \(c\), where \(c\) is the hypotenuse, we have \(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\).
\end{proposition}
```

If my cursor is on the middle line, and I press `M-q` (which executes `fill-paragraph`), then I obtain

```
\begin{proposition}
    For every right-angled triangle with side \(a,b\) and \(c\), where
    \(c\) is the hypotenuse, we have \(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\).
\end{proposition}
```

which has the correct indentation. However, if I select the middle line and press `M-q`, I get

```
\begin{proposition}
    For every right-angled triangle with side \(a,b\) and \(c\), where
\(c\) is the hypotenuse, we have \(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\).
\end{proposition}
```

As you see, the indentation of the second line is incorrect.

---

I did some more research and experimentation. According to the AUCTeX documentation on [Indenting](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Indenting), there is a special `LaTeX-fill-region`, which does not seem to suffer from my problem. *However*, when I have selected text, `M-q` uses `fill-region` instead of `LaTeX-fill-region`. How can I change this?

Comment: You’re going to need to make your question more detailed, with a more concrete example.

Comment: @db48x You are right, I added an example and realized this might be a problem specific to AUCTeX.

Comment: I don’t see the problem you’re describing.  Make sure `fill-paragraph-function` is set to `LaTeX-fill-paragraph`.  If it is and still not working as intended, try invoking `LaTeX-fill-paragraph` directly (by the default it is bound to C-c C-q C-p).

Comment: @d125q As explained in my last edit, the problem is that `M-q` uses `fill-region` instead of `LaTeX-fill-region`, when a region is selected.